# How to Datalayer.push a checkbox variable

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, push, google-datalayer

I was hoping if somebody could help me figure out how to get `datalayer.push` data from checkboxes the user has selected on a form during submission. The form has many fields but I only want the checkboxes that have been selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check when you are calling `dataLayer.push`
If the function is called after `document.ready` or on change or on form submit-event. As the case could be that the value of the checkbox is `undefined` at the time of `dataLayer.push` function call.

To get the value of checked checkbox use:

`$('.form-check__input:checked').serialize();`

Comment: I have validation on the form it wont let it submit without atleast one of the checkboxes checked, and javascript is set up so it only triggers the datalayer on a success. I think im calling out the variable the wrong way but i have no idea what the right way is

Comment: @FrankSentifolie can you check if you are only taking the value of checked checkboxes? I've updated my answer accordingly. Check it out.

Comment: Took me a week to find some time to continue working on this project and this perfectly helped me solve my problem  `$('.form-check__input:checked').serialize();`

Comment: Glad it helped :)